# SwiftUI or UIKit for animation?

Tags: xcode, animation, uikit, swiftui

I am starting to implement some animations to my app. As I started up with SwiftUI and had no experience on using UIKit, is the animation in SwiftUI enough for making customized animations? Or, should I try to learn UIKit and wrap it inside of SwiftUI View to achieve some more advanced animation?

Comment: Is there a particular animation that you're having trouble implementing in SwiftUI? It would likely be better to discuss that directly. SwiftUI can do many animations, but not everything that UIKit can do. The answer to "should I learn" is either "do you have a specific problem that you need it for, then yes" or "does it interest you, then yes." There's not really general answer if you're not running into any particular problem. SwiftUI can certainly customize animations, depending on how "customized" you mean.

Comment: (As a side note, as a long time Mac and iOS dev it really excites me that there is a whole new group coming in who only know SwiftUI. Welcome! You're at the ground floor of something very interesting.)

Comment: @RobNapier Thanks! I just started learning this month. The main problem is that most of the detailed tutorials on animations are on UIKit, especially in terms of gestures. For example, some SwiftUI tutorials on Youtube only teaches me how to make a specific type of animation or effect. As I had some app development experience, I definitely expect a more systematic illustration of how animations in SwiftUI work. I tried Udemy but most of SwiftUI classes are project oriented. And apple documentation is kind of too general. Let me know if there is any resources out there!

Comment: Ghazi's link to SwiftUI lab is a great source. See also hackingwithswift.com, which is one of the most extensive collections of SwiftUI examples available (also Swift generally). And despite its name, objc.io is a fantastic source of information on Swift and SwiftUI, including numerous custom animation examples in SwiftUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think SwiftUI is pretty much enough to use available animations, if that s not enough for you, you can check amazing custom animations made by SwiftUI LAB.

**[PART 1](https://swiftui-lab.com/swiftui-animations-part1) -- [PART 2](https://swiftui-lab.com/swiftui-animations-part2/) -- [PART3](https://swiftui-lab.com/swiftui-animations-part3/)**

It includes more than 20 diffrent animations, source code is available.